# Perform computation in a parallel iterator, then feed it to a single-threaded one?

Tags: multithreading, rust, rayon

Consider the following example:

```
use rayon::prelude::*;

fn do_something_expensive_returning_lots_of_data(x: u32) -> u32 {
    x
}

fn main() {
    let very_large_array = [1, 2, 3, 4];
    let mut h = std::collections::HashSet::new();
    very_large_array.par_iter().for_each({
        |x| {
            let c = do_something_expensive_returning_lots_of_data(*x);
            h.insert(c);
        }
    });
}
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
error[E0596]: cannot borrow `h` as mutable, as it is a captured variable in a `Fn` closure
  --> src/main.rs:13:13
   |
13 |             h.insert(c);
   |             ^ cannot borrow as mutable
```

My intention is to only have do_something_expensive_returning_lots_of_data executed in a multithreaded fashion, then once it executes, have a single-threaded iterator with results of the calls so that I could then safely mutate `h`. Is this possible with Rayon?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to mutate the hashmap in parallelized code you need to do the `Arc<Mutex<T>>` dance. Why not just collect the results in a HashSet like this:

```rust
use rayon::prelude::*;

fn do_something_expensive_returning_lots_of_data(x: u32) -> u32 {
    x
}

fn main() {
    let very_large_array = [1, 2, 3, 4];
    let h = very_large_array
        .par_iter()
        .map(|x| do_something_expensive_returning_lots_of_data(*x))
        .collect::<std::collections::HashSet<_>>();
}
```

(Edited after comment) If you want to process the values as they arrive I suggest using an mpsc channel like this:

```rust
use rayon::prelude::*;
use std::sync::mpsc::sync_channel;

fn do_something_expensive_returning_lots_of_data(x: u32) -> u32 {
    x
}

fn main() {
    let (sender, receiver) = sync_channel(1024); // choose appropriate buffer size
    let very_large_array = [1, 2, 3, 4];
    rayon::join(
        move || {
            very_large_array.par_iter().for_each(|x| {
                sender
                    .send(do_something_expensive_returning_lots_of_data(*x))
                    .unwrap()
            })
        },
        move || {
            while let Ok(x) = receiver.recv() {
                println!("{}", x)
            }
        },
    );
}
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=dd879a8acfad436da6c095b00469b2c7))

Comment: Thanks! That would work, but in my case the structure is a bit more nested: it's actually a HashMap<Vec<String>, HashSet<_>>. Because of that, I need to be able to post-process the data as it arrives, outside of the parallel iterator but not all at once.

Comment: I have edited my answer to match this requirement.

Answer (score 0):

This one is pretty simple: instead of adding elements to the `HashSet` one at a time during computation, map the data with your computation and then collect it into a HashSet.

```rust
use rayon::prelude::*;

fn do_something_expensive_returning_lots_of_data(x: u32) -> u32 {
    x
}

fn main() {
    let very_large_array = [1u32, 2, 3, 4];
    let h = very_large_array
        .into_par_iter()
        .map(do_something_expensive_returning_lots_of_data)
        .collect::<std::collections::HashSet<_>>();
    println!("{:?}", h);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=a3eaffacbda39995f36de290076691c7)

It is important to realize that Rayon has a parallel analog of all of `std::iter`'s components. If you need to extend an existing `HashSet` you can use the `par_extend` method.

```rust
use rayon::prelude::*;

fn do_something_expensive_returning_lots_of_data(x: u32) -> u32 {
    x
}

fn main() {
    let very_large_array = [1u32, 2, 3, 4];
    let mut h = std::collections::HashSet::new();
    h.par_extend(
        very_large_array
            .into_par_iter()
            .map(do_something_expensive_returning_lots_of_data),
    );
    println!("{:?}", h);
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=8c9de1688418b47b144d4e37edb3ebbd)